# Laravel Passing Data to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I just starting learning laravel and was wondering how to pass data unrelated to the route to a controller. What I'm trying to accomplish is create a todo item that is able to have nested items.

## View

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('lists.items.create',4)}}">Create New Item</a>
```

The 4 is just a hard-coded example to see if it was working.

## Controller

```
public function create(TodoList $list, $item_id = null)
{
    dd($item_id);
    return view('items.create', compact('list'));
}
```

So if your creating an item and don't pass in a parameter for id, it will default to `null` otherwise set it to whatever was passed in. However I'm getting a `NotFoundHttpException`. How would I be able to accomplish this.

Any help Welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the route, for example:

```
Route::get('create-item/{id}', [
    'as' => 'lists.items.create', 
    'uses' => 'MyController@create'
])
```

Now, call the route like:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('lists.items.create', ['id' => 4])}}">Create New Item</a>
```

Comment: Figured I'd need another route. Thanks for the help.