# laravel 5 cannot get into the specify controller method

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

My route:

```
Route::get('register/verify/{activation_code}', 'Auth\AuthController@confirm');
```

in Authcontroller.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{


    public function create(array $data)
    {
         //do something
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function confirm($activation_code)
    {
             //do something
    }


    public function approval($id)
    {
          //do something
    }

}
```

But this route works:

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

It can reach create function through Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php

Comment: can you explain your question better?

Comment: Is that your entire controller class? RegisterUsers is a trait, and I don't see a 'use' statement here.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allowed too much code, so I did not put it here

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201692/laravel-passing-data-to-controller

Comment: Can you paste the content of your log files in storage/logs folder?